# java cannot find symbol variable super

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, super, cannot-find-symbol

hello i'm super stuck and cannot work out why this is not working. i'm trying to use inheritance and override but i keep getting this error. Been trying to figure this out for the past hour but have had no clue. i'm probably missing something silly, any help would be hugely grateful.

```
public class FlyingDragon extends Entity {
private int Hp;
public FlyingDragon(int x, int y, int Hp){
    super (x, y);
    this.Hp = Hp;
}
public void setHp(int Hp){
    this.Hp = 100;
}

public int getHp(){
   return Hp;}

public void setType(String type) { ###error is here
 super.setType("Flying Dragon");}
}

    public abstract class Entity { 
private char symbol; // symbol that represents the entity
private String type; // every entity is of a type
private int x; // x coordinate in the room
private int y; // y coordinate in the room


 public Entity (int x, int y) {
 type = "entity";
 this.x=x;
 this.y =y;
}



 public char getSymbol() {
   return symbol;
  }

 public void setSymbol(char c) {
     symbol = c;
  }

 public int getX() {
   return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
   return y;
  }
  public void setX (int newx) {
     this.x=newx;

   }

   public void setY (int newy) {
     this.y=newy;

   }
    public String getType() {
      return type;
     }

  public void setType(String type) {
     this.type = type;
     }
  }
```

Comment: You defined setter as `setType` but used `type`.

Comment: Still the same error but thankyou for the advice

Comment: Why override the setter at all?

Comment: suppose `public abstract class Entity { }` is missing a } at the end.

Comment: yeah sorry its not in my program, again thankyou for the input

Comment: what is the error you're facing?

Comment: Are both your classes in the same file? Java does not like multiple public classes in the same file.

Comment: Cannot find symbol variable super. Seems as though the syntax is not reading in the entity properly

Comment: yeah they both are in the same folder

Comment: Same folder or same .java file?

Comment: not the same .java file

Comment: same package though

Comment: remove public from first class

Comment: Unable to reproduce (using version #3 of question). To prove that, I removed `public` from both classes, so I could put them both in same .java file, and it compiles fine on [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/x9VI9V). See output: **`Compiles and runs ok`**

Comment: i'm using net beans and also been told to keep them in seperate .java files

Comment: but again thank you for your help

Comment: @PatrickScottJackson How are you compiling the code?

Answer (score 0):

Change method `setType` of `FlyingDragon` to :

```
public void setType(String type) {
        super.setType("Flying Dragon");
    }
```

Comment: tried that but still hasn't worked, thankyou for your input though !

Comment: What else problems do you have?

Comment: exactly the same error, Cannot find symbol variable super

Comment: Try to put these two classes in separate .java files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make separate file for Entity class put all Entity code into this class.

**Entity Class:**

```
public abstract class Entity { 
private char symbol; // symbol that represents the entity
private String type; // every entity is of a type
private int x; // x coordinate in the room
private int y; // y coordinate in the room


 public Entity (int x, int y) {
 type = "entity";
 this.x=x;
 this.y =y;
}



 public char getSymbol() {
   return symbol;
  }

 public void setSymbol(char c) {
     symbol = c;
  }

 public int getX() {
   return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
   return y;
  }
  public void setX (int newx) {
     this.x=newx;

   }

   public void setY (int newy) {
     this.y=newy;

   }
    public String getType() {
      return type;
     }

  public void setType(String type) {
     this.type = type;
     }
    }
```

Now create separate class for FlyingDragon.

**FlyingDragon Class**

```
public class FlyingDragon extends Entity {
private int Hp;
public FlyingDragon(int x, int y, int Hp){
    super(x, y);
    this.Hp = Hp;
}
public void setHp(int Hp){
    this.Hp = 100;
}

public int getHp(){
   return Hp;}

public void setType(String type) { //###error is here
 super.setType("Flying Dragon");}
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        FlyingDragon d = new FlyingDragon(1,2,3);

        //whatever you want to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type, thats the error i got

Comment: which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Make sure when you use his source code you also get the ```public class Test {``` in his Test class. Its not in the normal code section so you may have missed that.

Comment: im on net beans